# Set a flag for Robo Electric test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Is there any way we can detect if activity is running for roboelectric test cases? I want to exclude some code if roboelectric test cases are running for the activity being tested.

Comment: Can you explain which code? It is quite bad practice to change your production code to compile with test code